# Scala Play Templates: Reverse routing with HTTP POST

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

when reverse routing to a GET route, i simply do

```
<a href="@controllers.routes.Application.sayHello()">Hello</a>
```

this means theres a GET route to the sayHello function. What if it was POST and needed an attached payload? is the POST implicit? how is the payload data attached?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP method for the reverse router is derived from your route configuration file.

Here is an example from a route configuration where I have two different requests with the same URL but different HTTP methods pointing to different methods:

```
GET     /login                              controllers.Application.login
POST    /login                              controllers.Application.authenticate
```

The *login()* method in the Application controller simply streams out the HTML form:

```
def login = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(html.loginForm(loginForm))
}
```

the *authenticate()* method however binds the request to a form allowing further processing:

```
def authenticate = Action { implicit request =>
   loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
       formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.loginForm(formWithErrors)),
       user => {
            // OTHER CODE HERE
            Redirect(routes.Blog.createPost).withSession("user" -> user)
       }
   )      
}
```

This second method requires a form definition in the controller:

```
val loginForm = Form(
    tuple(
        "username" -> text,
        "password" -> text
        ) verifying ("Invalid username or password", result => result match {
            case (username, password) => Account.authenticate(username, password).isDefined
        })
    )
```

So depending which method you put to the reverse router in your view, that is the HTTP method which will be used for the request.